# Mysql transaction check error

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install mysql on amazon ec2 instance. And I am getting following error.
Please help me to fix it.

```
$ sudo yum install mysql-server
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.15.0.0 from install of MariaDB-compat-5.5.54-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.23-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0 from install of MariaDB-compat-5.5.54-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.23-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.15.0.0 from install of MariaDB-compat-5.5.54-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.23-1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0 from install of MariaDB-compat-5.5.54-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.23-1.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command:

`rpm -e MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.23-1.el7.x86_64`

Then try to install again:

`sudo yum install mysql-server`